# Chain rule and implicit dfferentiation

Tags: calculus

We are given that $y(x)=e^{z(x)}$. I want to show $$z''(x) = \frac{y''(x)}{y(x)}-\left(\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}\right)^{2}$$

But I can't seem to get to this result. Since $y=e^{z}$ then $z=\ln{(y)}$, so $z'=\frac{
y'}{y}$. Now my problem is within the second derivative: $$z'' = \frac{{\rm d}^{2}z}{{\rm d}x^{2}}=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right) = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}y}\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d} x}$$ $$= \left(\frac{y''}{y} - \frac{y'}{y^{2}}\right)y' = \frac{y''y'}{y}-\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)^{2}.$$ So I have an extra factor of $y'$ in the first term. What have I done incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have $z'(x) = y'(x)/y(x)$, then $$z''(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)} \right],$$ and you evaluate this via the quotient rule:  $$z''(x) = \frac{(y'(x))' y(x) - y'(x)y'(x)}{y(x)^2} = \frac{y'' y}{y^2} - \frac{(y')^2}{y^2}.$$  I don't know how you went from the fourth expression to the fifth; i.e., the fourth equality seems dubious to me.

Comment: I was differentiating using the chain rule just like I did for $z'$. ie. $$z' = \frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}y}\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}y}y' = \frac{y'}{y}.$$

Comment: you can't use the chain rule on operators, it only works for derivatives of functions - look up the theorem and you'll see there is nothing about the differentiation operator @user2850514, i.e. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \neq \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}$$

Comment: @user2850514 But $y$ is already a function of $x$.

Comment: So if this is not correct how is $z=y'/y$? Surely in this case it should be $z'=1/y$.

Comment: $z' = y'/y$ because of the chain rule - $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: @user2850514 No.  In ALL of the computations, the prime symbol is understood to denote differentiation with respect to $x$, not $y$.

Comment: So as I said above we use the chain rule. ie. $$z' = \frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}y}\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}y}y'=\frac{y'}{y}.$$ By the chain rule. This is correct, right? Since $z'$ is a function of $y$ and $y$ is a function of $x$. So we have used the chain rule, so why don't we use the chain rule for $z''$?

Comment: @user2850514 $\frac{\text{d}z}{\text{d}y} \neq z'$

Comment: @user2850514 Yes, but that's not the same type of computation you are attempting in the evaluation of $z''(x)$, because you wrote $$\frac{dz}{dy} \cdot y',$$ rather than $$\frac{d}{dy} \cdot y',$$ the latter of which doesn't make sense.  Even if you meant $$\frac{d}{dy} \left[ \frac{y'}{y} \right],$$ *that too does not make sense*.  It certainly doesn't evaluate to what you think it does.

Comment: Sorry I just don't understand how you're not using the chain rule for $z''$. We are differentiating $y$ with respect to $x$ so we must therefore use the chain rule.

Comment: If I told you that $$f(x) = g(x) \cdot \frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$ for some unknown function $g$ of $x$, then how would you compute $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}?$$  **EVERY** function I have furnished here is a function of $x$ only.

Comment: Consider the function $v(y) = y'/y$. So $z''= \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}y}\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}y}y'$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: To answer the above, just let $$h(x) = \frac{dg(x)}{dx} = g'(x)$$ and use the product rule $$f'(x) = g(x) h'(x) + g'(x) h(x).$$  But since $h(x) = g'(x)$, then $h'(x) = g''(x).$

Comment: How on earth would you calculate $dv/dy$?  Remember, $y$ is a function of $x$.  If you are differentiating $v$ with respect to $y$, how do you take into account $y'$ in the numerator?  Because I guarantee you that $$\frac{d}{dy}[y'(x)] \ne y''(x).$$

Comment: Ah ok I can see, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chain rule on $y(x)$ to get $$y'(x) = e^{z(x)}\cdot z'(x)$$ and then use the chain and product rule on $y'(x)$ to get $$y''(x) = e^{z(x)}\cdot (z'(x))^2+z''(x)e^{z(x)}$$ Now you can solve for $z''$ and should get $$z''(x) = \frac{y''(x)- e^{z(x)}\cdot (z'(x))^2}{e^{z(x)}}$$ Next you can substitute $y(x) = e^{z(x)}$ and $z'(x) = \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$ into your equation for $z''$ such that $$z''(x) = \frac{y''(x)- y(x)\cdot \left( \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}\right)^2}{y(x)} \\ =  \frac{y''(x)}{y(x)}- \frac{y(x)\cdot \left( \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}\right)^2}{y(x)} \\ = \frac{y''(x)}{y(x)}-\left( \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}\right)^2$$